# Where was this scene from The Revenant filmed?

Tags: film-location, the-revenant

I was really impressed by this scene in *The Revenant*:

[image: Scene]

Could anyone tell me where it was filmed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Revenant_%282015_film%29#Filming):

> The film was shot in twelve locations in three countries: Canada, the
>   United States, and Argentina. In Canada, filming took place in Calgary
>   and Fortress Mountain in Alberta, and at Squamish and Mammoth Studios,
>   Burnaby, in British Columbia.While the initial plan was to film
>   entirely in Canada, the weather was ultimately too warm, leading the
>   filmmakers to locations at the tip of Argentina with snow on the
>   ground, to shoot the film's ending.

It seems that *That* scene was shot in Kananaskis Country situated west of Calgary ([source](http://www.atlasofwonders.com/2016/01/the-revenant-filming-locations.html)).

Answer (score 3):

This specific scene was shot in Spray Lake's Provincial Park. Leo's character is actually walking on a frozen lake!  Most of the locations shot in Canada are in the Kananaskis and neighboring provincial parks.

Seebe/Morley - Native Reserve,
Spray Lakes,
Kananaskis Country,
Dead Man's Flats - 10 Mins outside of Canmore and near an area called Exshaw,
Fortress Mountain - Peter Lougheed Provincial Park - Former ski area/unsure if it's still a catski operation, Tent Ridge Area.

The other Canadian location(s) were in BC.